# How to remove the letter 'a' from boxplot legend- ggplot2, I am not using geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

thanks for your help.

I am making a simple boxplot with p value markers and a legend in r using ggplot() and aes(). This generates a legend with boxplots as markers- which is what I was trying to do- but the legend includes the letter 'a' inside the markers. [screenshot of the legend here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xam1l.png)

I don't want the letter to show up in the legend- just the boxplot marker.

I've found several solutions to this problem on stack overflow that involve setting show.legend to False in geomtext(). However, I didn't use geomtext() when making the plot. I tried adding a line with geomtext(show.legend = False) in the call to make the boxplot. I tried adding show.legend = FALSE inside of aes() and inside theme() and theme_classic(), but those solutions did not work.

I gather that it's showing some kind of text legend as well as the boxplot marker- how do I remove that legend? Am I using geomtext() incorrectly or is there another way?

Here's the code for the boxplot-

```
p<-ggplot(data=df,aes(x = welldata,y =efficiency, color = yeardata))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0.8)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("cornflowerblue","goldenrod1"))+
  labs(color="Year")+scale_x_discrete(name= "Distance From Creek (m)")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Fraction of Tidal Influence")+
  ggtitle("Fraction of Tidal Influence vs Distance From Tidal Creek")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12))

p+stat_compare_means(aes(group=year),label = "p.signif")
df%>%group_by(year,well)%>% get_summary_stats(efficiency, type="mean_sd")
df%>%group_by(year,well)%>% get_summary_stats(efficiency, type="mean_sd")
```

Comment: You don't use geom_text. But `ggpubr::stat_compare_means` does under the hood. Try with adding `show.legend=FALSE` to `ggpubr::stat_compare_means`. See `?ggpubr::stat_compare_means`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!